# Distribute text within a shape

Tags: c#, string, geometry

I have an array of simple strings (simple meaning 1-4 words, not in complete sentences) that I want to distribute "evenly" within an arbitrary shape.

By "evenly" I mean that the text does whatever it can to not overlap other text, but all the strings aren't bunched up in one particular location.  I don't mean that the text has to be the max distance from eachother, I just want to fill the space as best as I can.

Example:

I have the following array:

```
var array = new [] {"#WhatIDidLastWeek", "Salena Gomez", "#WWF", "#IThinkOomf", "CES" };
```

and I have a circle of radius `600px` that I want every string in the `array` to be inside that circle and be spaced far enough appart that they don't overlap and that the general shape of the circle is apparent.

Comment: What display technology are you using?  WPF?  WinForms?  Are you just spitting out an image?

Comment: Well, right now I'm just concerned about the xy, then I'm passing it to whatever view.  This is a library so it will work with everything from WPF to ASP.net

Comment: btw - I should down vote just for having a reference to Justin Bieber.  <g>

Comment: Ha!  I'll edit it then :) If you couldn't tell, this is going to be for a Twitter app.  That was the hint.  *CHANGED*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use some sort of [MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) call in whatever environment you're working with.

The basic idea is measure each word to see if it will fit in the allotted space.  If it doesn't fit, move it down to the next "line".  The hard part will be what to do when you run out of space to fit all the words.